# is it possible to write two listener for one container in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

In my application i have view flipper is it possible to use onclick, ontouch listener for one view flipper ...

I tried but its working half. suppose onclick works fine , ontouch listener not working same for on touch listener. i tried to use onclick listener for whole layout and ontouch listener for view flipper but this also not working.

On touch Listener :

```
viewFilper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Here the code for flip the pages
      return true;
      }
});
```

on click Listener :

```
viewFilper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Here i use intent to change activity regarding with the details of view flipper
     }
});
```

so how can i use onclick and ontouch listener for a same container?

i need your help buddies. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The OnTouchListener should be working fine, the problem is that you return true, so you "absorb" the touch event and the OnClickListener doesn´t work.

If you return false on the touch listener and true on the click it should work fine.

If you will be using the touch listener for moving the View, the OnClick wont get called because the touch event wont be absorbed so I suggest you return true just if the View was moved or released.

Example:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean  onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
            iAction = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (iAction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // your code here
                bExitValue = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                bExitValue = false;
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //no need to set to true because it has already gone through ACTION_MOVE, if it didn't it will return false and the click listener will absorb it
            break;

    }
    return (bExitValue);        
}
});

    viewFilper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
         //your code
      }
    });
```

Comment: im not cleared.. im fine with ontouch listener but how to write onclick listener could you pls edit you answer with onclick listener

Comment: Sorry for that, just try not returning anything